# Select / Delete of Three self referencing many to many relationships SQL Query

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, recursive-query, database-cursor

I have a table ProjectLayerContent designed as following:

1. ProjectLayerContentID [INT]
2. ProjectLayerContentName [NVARCHAR(200)]
3. ProjectLayerContentParentID [INT]
4. ScopeIsProjectLayerContent [BIT]
5. ScopeIsProjectLayerContentID [INT]
6. DataTypeIsContentOfContent [BIT]
7. ContentOfContentID [INT]

   - The project layer content might have a parent, and might not, also the same for the children.
   - The project layer content scope might include another project layer content.
   - The project layer content data type might be a type of another content.

What I am trying to do is in the delete process, I want to show a list includes the count of what's is going to be deleted if you will delete this project layer content.
Pretty much this is what I got into, but I know those results isn't right

```
    DECLARE @ProjectLayerContentID INT = 1;
DECLARE @resTable TABLE (
    ProjectLayerContentIDP int,
    ProjLContentType nvarchar(100));

    DECLARE @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam int;
    DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(MAX);

    DECLARE @resultString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

    -- SELECT Project layer content children with recursion

-- SELECT the count of the result from the recursion of the children of the project layer content id passed with the sql parameter in the query
        DECLARE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID, 'Child(ren)'
        FROM    ProjectLayerContent
        WHERE   ProjectLayerContentParentID = @ProjectLayerContentID

        OPEN ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO @resTable SELECT @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type;
                        ;WITH ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeChildren AS(
                        SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID,CAST('Content(s) of Child(ren)' as varchar(259))   AS ProjLContentType
                        FROM    ProjectLayerContent
                        WHERE   ContentOfContentID = @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  Scopechildren.ProjectLayerContentID, CAST('Children Content Of Content of Child(ren)' as varchar(259)) AS ProjLContentType
                        FROM    ProjectLayerContent Scopechildren INNER JOIN
                                ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeChildren projLContents ON Scopechildren.ContentOfContentID = projLContents.ProjectLayerContentID
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT  children.ProjectLayerContentID, CAST('Child(ren) of Child(ren) of Child(ren)' as varchar(259)) AS ProjLContentType
                        FROM    ProjectLayerContent children INNER JOIN
                                ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeChildren projLContents ON children.ProjectLayerContentParentID = projLContents.ProjectLayerContentID
                        )
                        INSERT INTO @resTable SELECT ProjectLayerContentID, ProjLContentType from ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeChildren
                                            FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                END
        -- close the cursor
        CLOSE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor
        DEALLOCATE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor


    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        -- SELECT Project layer content Scope children with recursion
        DECLARE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID, 'Content Of Content'
        FROM    ProjectLayerContent
        WHERE   ContentOfContentID = @ProjectLayerContentID


        OPEN ProjectLayerContent_Cursor
        FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContent_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                    BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO @resTable SELECT @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type;
                            ;WITH ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeContentOfContent AS(
                            SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID,CAST('Children Content Of Content' as varchar(259))   AS ProjLContentType
                            FROM    ProjectLayerContent
                            WHERE   ContentOfContentID = @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  Scopechildren.ProjectLayerContentID, CAST('Children Content Of Content of Children Content Of Content' as varchar(259)) AS ProjLContentType
                            FROM    ProjectLayerContent Scopechildren INNER JOIN
                                    ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeContentOfContent projLContents ON Scopechildren.ContentOfContentID = projLContents.ProjectLayerContentID
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT  children.ProjectLayerContentID, CAST('Children of Children Content Of Content' as varchar(259)) AS ProjLContentType
                            FROM    ProjectLayerContent children INNER JOIN
                                    ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeContentOfContent projLContents ON children.ProjectLayerContentParentID = projLContents.ProjectLayerContentID
                            )
                            INSERT INTO @resTable SELECT ProjectLayerContentID, ProjLContentType from ProjectLayerContentTotalScopeContentOfContent
                                                FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContent_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                END
        -- close the cursor
        CLOSE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor
        DEALLOCATE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor

        --select the result to present it.
        SELECT * FROM @resTable;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have way too much going on here. Without an easy to pick up table schema and meaningful test data, no one is likely to jump in. https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask might help.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but the table is more complicated, and have more relations than those three with each other, according to that I was trying to simplify the question as much as I can toward the problem I am facing, and I've got the answer, but didn't have time to post it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that this solution to get the needed functionality as needed.

I created the stored procedure to get all children for this project layer first, and created a table to add the result in. Because one of the first error to apply this solution was INSERT INTO EXEC wouldn't work if you have a chain of stored procedures calling each other. It only works for the first time, but the other times will show an error.

```
DECLARE @ProjectLayerContentID INT = 1;
DECLARE @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam INT;
DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @resultString NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

-------Create temp table to insert the results into it
CREATE TABLE #ResTable(
ProjectLayerContentIDP int,
ProjLContentType nvarchar(100));
```

Then I created a cursor for the select statement of all children who have that relationship of being child of this project layer, or being content of it.

```
-- SELECT Project layer content children with recursion

-- SELECT the count of the result from the recursion of the children of the project layer content id passed with the sql parameter in the query

DECLARE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID, CASE WHEN ProjectLayerContentParentID = @ProjectLayerContentID THEN 'Child(ren)' ELSE 'Content(s) of Content(s)' END
FROM    ProjectLayerContent
WHERE   ProjectLayerContentParentID = @ProjectLayerContentID
        OR ContentOfContentID = @ProjectLayerContentID

OPEN ProjectLayerContent_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContent_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #ResTable SELECT @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type;
```

Then I will call the recursion stored procedure to get each of the current project layer content chlidren, and content of the children.

```
Exec DeleteCheck_ProjectLayerContentChildren @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam;
                    FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContent_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                END
    -- close the cursor
    CLOSE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor
    DEALLOCATE ProjectLayerContent_Cursor
```

At this part here, we will select the results, and then drop the temp table from the database server.

```
        --select the result to present it.
SELECT @resultString =  @resultString + '<br/><u>' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Count(ProjectLayerContentIDP)) + '</u> ' + ProjLContentType
FROM #ResTable
GROUP BY ProjLContentType;
SELECT @resultString;
DROP TABLE #ResTable
```

**Here is the recursion stored procedure that we called already in the previous query**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE  [dbo].[DeleteCheck_ProjectLayerContentChildren]
    @ProjectLayerContentID INT
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam INT;
    DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(MAX);

    -- SELECT Project layer content children with recursion

-- SELECT the count of the result from the recursion of the children of the project layer content id passed with the sql parameter in the query.
```

Notice here we added Local into the deceleration of the cursor, because it will show an error of creating the cursor with the same name

```
        DECLARE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
        SELECT  ProjectLayerContentID, CASE WHEN ProjectLayerContentParentID = @ProjectLayerContentID THEN 'Child(ren) of Child(ren)' ELSE 'Child(ren) Content(s) of Content(s)' END
        FROM    ProjectLayerContent
        WHERE   ProjectLayerContentParentID = @ProjectLayerContentID
                OR ContentOfContentID = @ProjectLayerContentID
```

Pretty much most of this query is the same, as the previous one, but this is for the project layer content children of children counts, and we don't create the result table again because it will be already created, then we just add the result, and we have the needed functionality, and you can apply it to more than two or three self relationships.

```
OPEN ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor
            FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
                        BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO #ResTable SELECT @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type;
                            Exec DeleteCheck_ProjectLayerContentChildren @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam
                            FETCH NEXT FROM ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor INTO @ProjectLayerContentIDRecursionParam, @Type
                        END
            -- close the cursor
            CLOSE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor
            DEALLOCATE ProjectLayerContentChildren_Cursor
    END
```